# In Oracle 10g, how can I list schema objects and the privileges I can grant them?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Using SQL, I would like to create a list of certain schema objects (3-4 of them, tables and views) and the privileges I can grant them as the SYS user, or any other user I may be logged in as.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of pre-defined Oracle Object privileges available for different type of schema objects.
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm#i2077938

In order for a user to grant object privileges (any one of the pre-defined object privileges mentioned above) to other users, the user must be the owner of the object or the user must have been granted the object privileges WITH GRANT OPTION.  Otherwise, the user must have been given "GRANT ANY OBJECT PRIVILEGE" system privilege.

Suppose, when user U1 logs in,

1) To get a list of objects owned by the user which could be granted to other users

```
SELECT object_name FROM user_objects;
```

2) To get the list of object grants given to user U1, that could be granted to other users by U1.

```
SELECT grantor, grantee, table_name, owner 
  FROM user_tab_privs 
 WHERE grantee = 'U1' and grantable = 'YES'
```

3) To see whether U1 has GRANT ANY OBJECT PRIVILEGE, query

```
SELECT * FROM user_sys_privs where privilege = 'GRANT ANY OBJECT PRIVILEGE';
```

Answer (score 0):

sys can grant anything.

and the object themselves will come from one or more of the oracle data dictionary objects.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I would still like something that I can use to list the above, I've edited the question to make that clear.